# rake db:populate rake aborted! undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm following the Rails tutorials from [here](http://french.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code%3auser_reverse_relationships).

But at chapter 12.2 when I'm running `db:populate`, I get this error on line 54:

> rake aborted! undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

So okay following seems to be empty, but what should I do to fix it?

[Here is my related code](https://github.com/xavierva/sample_app2/blob/following-user/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake)

Comment: from the code, the only thing I can think of to raise that error is when you have only 2 users in your db (which is not the case if the rake task runs properly).  If you only have 2 users, `followers.each` will cause that error.

Comment: Hi, I did some relecture from my code with a fresh morning brain, and and i realised that my code was messy. So I could solve my issue pretty easily. Thanks for your time. Corrected code is on the same repo.